# Tree Grid View binding errors on collection change

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, observablecollection

I have a WPF MVVM application that contains a custom tree grid view that gets its information from an observable collection.

If I run the application without changing anything in the observable collection, it runs fine.

However if I change items within the observable collection I get the following error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'TreeListViewItem' (Name=''); target property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')
```

Any ideas as to how I would solve this?

Comment: how do ou change content of the collection ?

Comment: It's being changed with a timer event. On the event call, I have another collection which I loop through and add only the valid items to the list that is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [very short blog post](http://blog.jtango.net/using-a-grid-as-the-itemspanel-for-a-listbox) this error can happen when you try to bind `ListBoxItems`.  Now in your error above, you are having trouble with a target element of `TreeListViewItem` but I could definitely see how this could be the same problem.  Could you try  one of the two methods for fixing this that the blog suggests?  Both are simply creating a custom style for the TreeListViewItem (or in his case a ListBoxItem).  The two suggestions are to:

1. Explicitly set the HorizontalContentAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment property
2. Set OverridesDefaultStyle to true and just ignore the value

   ```
   <Style x:Key="DeviceContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
   <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
   ```

Or:

```
    <Style x:Key="DeviceContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
```

You would, of course, change these for `TreeListViewItem` not for `ListBoxItem`.  =)